# Access a button from another class on EventTrigger in WPF (XAML)

Tags: wpf, class, xaml, eventtrigger

What I'm trying to do is when I click on a button "testButton" that's inside a page, to trigger an event that's inside a Border that's inside a Window.Resource inside of the MainWindow. If I remove the SourceName="testButton" from the EventTrigger it works with every button, what I want is to work only with that specific button.

```
<Window x:Class="test.mainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:mainWindow}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Border Padding="5">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="bgBrush" Color="Transparent" />
                            </Border.Background>
                              <Border.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="testButton">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="bgBrush"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Color"
                                                        From="Transparent"
                                                        To = "White"
                                                        Duration="0:0:01.00"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                     </BeginStoryboard>
                                 </EventTrigger>
                             </Border.Triggers>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

And here is the Page that the button is in:

```
<Page x:Class="test.testPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
      mc:Ignorable="d" Width="300" Height="200">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="testButton" Height="20" Width="50" Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: is it a MMVM based App or normal?

Comment: I don't know the difference, I'm new to whole XAML thing.

Comment: Then you might be trying more advance.  Go with basics will help you a lot.  Read event trigger and try to fire directly inside main window.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing sample code which will **change your MainWindow Background Color to Red on clicking button in Page**. It will help you understanding Routed Events.There are different approaches. I created one custom event to achieve this. Here is your code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bUNjAQRJpWSEpLV1JJeXQ4N1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have another problem, what I want to do is set this style to change background color to a border instead of the hole mainWindow, I've tried like this:
1. changed this -> <Style x:Key="test" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
2. I've define colums for grid to identify only the border background
3. added this -> <Border Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource test}"/>
But it doesn't seem to do something when i press the button.

Comment: For changing the windows border you need to work on window template.  Use blend to modify styles.  I will share one code soon. There is already lot of negative marking happening. On my answers.  But i answered your main question